# How null reference to an object can invoke static method?

Tags: java

How null reference to an object can invoke static method. Here is the sample code

```
class A{
public static void show(){
System.out.println("In Show");
}
psvm(..)
{
A a = null;
a.show();
}
```

Here as an output "In Show" is printed. I was expecting NPE . Request an understanding

Comment: There is no need for an instance while invoking static member or method.

Since static members belongs to class rather than instance.

Comment: @suresh agreed but we explicity assigned null to the reference

Comment: you are talking about the value of instance. I am telling that type of instance enough.

Comment: @Abhishek you'll also find it doesn't matter what that objects real type is (e.g. A child class) all that matters is the declared type. Really static methods shouldn't ever be called on instances like this

Answer (score 1):

Because you're really calling A.show(), since the method is static. It doesn't really need the instance a.